# Counting rows with the same name in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I'm new to PowerBi and I need some help with DAX for counting the rows with the same name.
I have a table like that:

| Name | Cost |
| --- | --- |
| Albert | 2137 |
| Daniel | 2234 |
| Albert | 2137 |
| Mark | 2234 |

And I want to know how many times did the name appeared so it would look like that:
| Name     |  Cost    |  NameCount |
| -------- | -------- |------------|
| Albert   | 2137     | 2          |
| Daniel   | 2234     | 1          |
| Albert   | 2137     | 2          |
| Mark     | 2234     | 1          |

I need it as all of the rows with the same name have the same cost and I would like to make another visual that would show the cumulative sum of all the distinct Cots ( so I would add the Albert value once not twice ) and I wanted to just make then another column that would be Cost/NameCount and the visual to show the sum of that.

I tried that but for it gives me 3 so just gives a number of distinct Names:

CountName =
VAR CurName = MAX(Parents[ParentName])
VAR Result = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(Parents),FILTER(Parents,Parents[ParentName] = CurName))
Return Result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NameCount = CALCULATE(COUNT('Table'[Name]),ALLEXCEPT('Table','Table'[Name]))
```

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot, It works for me but give me a number of all the times that that name is in the dataset not how many times in the filtered page, do you maybe know how to change it?

Comment: no worries. if works then can you help remark it as accepted answer so others can also find the solution. for filtered page, not quiet understood your question, do you have any images?

Comment: @Jakobee Hi Jakobee, you can edit the question with images for new problems so i can help you